# Connecting an External Monitor to my laptop drops the frame rate

Tags: monitor, framerate

I have a gaming laptop, where I play games like Elden Ring and Hogwarts Legacy. The game runs perfectly in the laptop.

But, I recently got a monitor, and I was testing it out to see how the game runs. The frame rates dropped to 11 - 15 FPS. In laptop, it used to run with 40-50 FPS.

I feel like, the laptop is diverting a significant amount of power to the external monitor. Hence, the drop in frame rate. Obviously, the laptop is in charged state.

Am I correct, or is there anything wrong in the laptop ?

Comment: Does your monitor have its own GPU? Mine does; and I've seen games silently switch to the monitor GPU which is significantly inferior compared to the laptop GPU and causes performance issues when this happens.

Comment: Did you change the resolution to run the game on the monitor?

Comment: @Colin Yes I did

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No. It was a regular monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor has a higher resolution than your laptop screen and you have adjusted the settings in the games to match you monitors resolution then that would explain the performance drop.

You will have to keep the resolution in the game settings the same as before to maintain your FPS. Or you will have to lower other graphical settings to compensate for the higher resolution.